# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable JpegImageFile object

Tags: python, keras, model

I'm running a model on keras, I've the following function:

```
def result_show(test_data,filename):
    src_image, tar_image = test_data
    # generate image from source
    gen_image = model.predict(src_image)
    print(src_image.shape)
    src_image = src_image.reshape((256,256,1))
    print(src_image.shape)
    gen_image = np.squeeze(gen_image)

    gen_Lab = np.concatenate([src_image, gen_image],axis = 2)
    gen_rgb = lab2rgb(gen_Lab)
    gen_rgb = np.array(gen_rgb).astype('uint8')

    tar_image = tar_image[0,:,:,:]
    print(gen_image.shape,src_image.shape,tar_image.shape)
    tar_Lab = np.concatenate([src_image, tar_image],axis = 2)
    tar_rgb = lab2rgb(tar_Lab)
    tar_rgb = np.array(tar_rgb).astype('uint8')

    save_path = '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Thesis/output/lab/'+filename


    # plot all three images
    plot_whole_images(src_image, gen_rgb, tar_rgb,save_path)
```

but whenever I call the function, it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-657af1de80f7> in <cell line: 16>()
     14 # result_show(test_data, "sdfhkjsdf")
     15 
---> 16 result_show(test_data,"abcd")

<ipython-input-34-b1d19dfb20e1> in result_show(test_data, filename)
      1 def result_show(test_data,filename):
----> 2     src_image, tar_image = test_data
      3     # generate image from source
      4     gen_image = model.predict(src_image)
      5     print(src_image.shape)

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable JpegImageFile object
```

Any suggession how to solve it? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `test_data` supposed to be? Your code expects it to be something like a tuple with 2 items, but instead you passed a JpegImageFile object. Its the caller of this function that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely with this line `src_image, tar_image = test_data`, in this line you are attempting to assign src_image and tar_image to whatever value is inside test_data. To do this the value stored inside test_data must be something that can be unpacked/assigned to two new variables (i.e. a tuple).

The error message  `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable JpegImageFile object` is telling you that whatever is in test_data is not iterable/cannot be unpacked and assigned. I'd start by making sure test_data is the type you expect.